# QuickBlox - Add Push notification in one to one private chat

Tags: ios, quickblox

How can i able to send notification, when app is opened or not opened. I am not getting any proper guidelines in quick blox docs, to send notification between private chat.

Please guide me, how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, QuickBlox sends push notifications to offline users automatically if your opponent is offline

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Push_notifications_to_the_offline_users

what you need is:

1. Create APNS certificate and upload it to the Admin panel http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Creating_APNS_certificates
2. Subscribe users to push notifications http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios#Giving_a_user_a_Push_Notification_subscription

that's all, after this a user will be receiving pushes when he will be offline

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply. I am implementing as what u suggested.

Comment: push notification is working when device is locked. It does not work when app is minimized.  Could u tell me the reason...

Comment: push notification is working when device is locked. It does not work when app is minimized.